# vNext Owin Middleware

Tags: owin, asp.net-core, middleware

I have a simple middleware:

```
public class MiddlewareInterceptor
{
    RequestDelegate _next;
    public MiddlewareInterceptor(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public Task Invoke(HttpContext ctx)
    {
        ctx.Response.WriteAsync("<h2>From SomeMiddleWare</h2>");
        return _next(ctx);
    }
}
```

And in my Startup.cs Configure method, I hook it like so:

```
app.UseMiddleware<MiddlewareInterceptor>();
```

The above builds and the app seems to run fine, but my breakpoint in the interceptor Invoke method never hits.  And likewise, there is never any output.  I tried that with `Debug.WriteLine` also.

Now, I also tried this method:

```
public class MiddlewareInterceptor : OwinMiddleware
{
    public MiddlewareInterceptor(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next){}

    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(context.Request.Uri.ToString());
        await Next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

And in my Startup.cs Configure method, I hook it like so:

```
app.Use(next => new MiddlewareInterceptor(next).Invoke);
```

Unfortunately, the base `OwinMiddleware` constructor is looking for the next `OwinMiddleware` as a parameter, unlike ye olde `RequestDelegate`.  So my `app.Use` instantiation of my `MiddlewareInterceptor` fails because `next` is of type `RequestDelegate`.

Lastly, I have tried an inline function directly in the Configure method which also never hits the breakpoint:

```
app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Hello");
    await next();
});
```

So as it stands, it seems like I cant make a basic middleware interceptor using OWIN.  What am I missing?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/11/14/katana-asp-net-5-and-bridging-the-gap.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is the order of the aforementioned middleware in the pipeline? Make sure this executes before anything that will terminate the request part of the pipeline; eg. UseMvc();

Comment: Great to know, and thank you.  It was indeed swapped after the UseMvc().  You rock